# add a value to localstorage, instead of replacing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want the value from `newUsername` to be added to the `localStorage` **setUsernamesArray**, whereas in my code, it replaces the entire value.

#### Code

```js
$('#signUpButton').click(function() {
  var newUsername = $('#usernameSignInBox').val();
  signedUpUsernames.push(newUsername);
  localStorage.setItem('setUsernamesArray', signedUpUsernames);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add to the array, you must realise that the value in localStorage isn't an array, it is a string. If you want that string to represent an array, and you want to update that array, you must do the following things:

- read the string, `localStorage.getItem('setUsernamesArray')`,
- then convert it to an array with `JSON.parse`,
- then push to the array,
- and then store it again with `localStorage.setItem('setUsernamesArray', JSON.stringify(array))`

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage` always store values as a `string`, so `stringify` your `array` and store,

```
localStorage.setItem('setUsernamesArray', JSON.stringify(signedUpUsernames));
```

And before reading it just `parse` it,

```
var arrayFrmStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("setUsernamesArray"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage.setItem` will replace value of the key in localStorage.

Consider localStorage as a variable. when you do

```js
var a = "Hello";
a = " World"
```

value of `a` is replaced. To avoid it, we use `+=`

```js
var a = "Hello";
a += " World"
```

Similarly, you will have to create another object with updated value and write this to localStorage.

Following is an example.

```js
function setValueToLS(key, prop, value){
  var _local = {};
  if(localStorage.getItem(key))
    _local = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));

  _local[prop] = value;

  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(_local));
}
```